# Neo4j 2.1.3 missing neo4j-kernal test-jar

Tags: java, neo4j

I just tried upgrading to 2.1.3 and found the the following test-jar is missing from Maven Central:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.3</version>
   <type>test-jar</type>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am looking to use the TestGraphDatabaseFactory, any chance it moved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there, see http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/neo4j/neo4j-kernel/2.1.3/ having a `neo4j-kernel-2.1.3-tests.jar`.

I've just verified that the equivalent dependency in gradle just works fine:

```
testCompile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-kernel', version: '2.1.3', classifier: 'tests'
```

Maybe you're using Maven central behind a proxy that has not yet been updated?

Comment: And here's the docs on it, with a link to some code using it: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.1.3/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html

Comment: Your right the issue is on our end, the firewall blocked it b/c the file size was too bog. I did notice that the tests jar grew in size considerably b/w release, 2.1.2 is 2.1M and 2.1.3 is 9.2M ... something to worry about?